# What happens when support has ended for a specific version of Ubuntu?

Tags: support

So old versions of Ubuntu are unsupported. What does that mean?

Answer (score 7):

It means that you won't get security updates and selected high-impact bug fixes any longer.

Answer (score 3):

You can continue using your Ubuntu, without security updated and bug fixes, as @htorque said.

I would to add that you can also install new software available in the *frozen* repositories, simply substituting the server you are using in `sources.list` with the following

> http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/

Needless to say, you are strongly advised to upgrade to a newer release of Ubuntu.